# Starting with Lambda and Ec2 and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm trying to echo the path in my Lambda and my code is as below.

```
var SSH = require('simple-ssh');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = function index(event, context, callback) {
    var ssh = new SSH({
        host: 'MyIp',
        user: 'ec2-user',
        key: fs.readFileSync("./SampleEc2Lambda.pem")
    });

    ssh.exec('echo $PATH', {
        out: function (stdout) {
            console.log(stdout);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I am really sorry to say that I'm not aware of how I create it. I'm following the tutorial given at https://medium.com/@Electricste/run-shell-commands-on-a-ec2-from-a-lambda-function-108994911064 and I added an s3 trigger.

But when I run my above program, there is no error, but, instead when I run my Lambda Test event I get the output as `null`.

and in my cloud watch I get the log as

> START RequestId: 902bdb39-dc35-11e7-9d0a-738b98ef975c Version: $LATEST
>   END RequestId: 902bdb39-dc35-11e7-9d0a-738b98ef975c REPORT RequestId:
>   902bdb39-dc35-11e7-9d0a-738b98ef975c  Duration: 6.85 ms   Billed
>   Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB  Max Memory Used: 19 MB

in my browser when I key in http://MyIp/latest/meta-data/. this doesn't load up. but in my EC2 I see my instance with `MyIp` is in running state.

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish here. What is the exact question? Also, I don't see S3 being used here at all.

Comment: I was just trying to invoke EC2 from lambda... My apologies for including S3